# Date and name based friendly URL using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, friendly-url

I'm planning on switching from having my blog on wordpress.com to having it on my own site hosted on my own server. Naturally I want to preserve the link structure from wordpress so that no links to my blog out there on the WWW break.

So my question is, how do I get the following friendly URL

```
http://example.com/yyyy/mm/dd/post-name
```

to map to some structure like

```
http://example.com/index.php?page=bla-bla
```

on my server using .htaccess?

Can the identifier bla-bla be a simple integer id, or does it have to include both date and name, that would be yyyy-mm-dd-post-name?

Thanks in advance.

---

EDIT: Thank you for your quick replies. A few additions to my question though: I'm not currently using wordpress.org, so I don't have a control panel that can generate the file for me. At least I think not. And I'm also not going to use wordpress on my own server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make following work as you require .. put it in a .htaccess file.

```
# Options +FollowSymLinks  
# RewriteEngine On  
#   
# RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
# RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  
#   
# RewriteRule ^page/(\d+)*$ ./page.php?id=$1
```

To read all of the details .. [click here to read "friendly and pretty urls"](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls/)

Comment: Thank you. Your link reminded me that it can all be done in PHP if .htaccess redirects everything to a control page like index.php.

Answer (score 0):

There's a setting on the WordPress control panel that you can activate, and a .htaccess file provided with WordPress that lets it work. It lets you set up the URL's any way you want.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has permalinks built-in and will create an appropriate `.htaccess` file for you.
If you're going to use WordPress on your own domain as well, that is.

Answer (score 0):

If your host is a Linux server, the rewrite will be supported out of the box. If you host is a Windows server, you will need a rewrite plugin installed.

Windows server is running Helicon Tech ISAPI_Rewrite v3, and it works perfectly fine after I:

Turned the plugin on

```
In Helm: Home > Domains >  domain_name > Website Extensions > URL Rewriting
```

Wrote my rewrite correctly

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* /blog/index.php [NC,L]
<blank line>
```

Changed my WordPress permalinks to custom

```
/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/
```