# WordPress Like Permalinks

Tags: php, wordpress

Working on a project that is WordPress Like *

Idea is:
In a a data table I have two fields
`actual_link` and `target_link`

What I am looking to do is display a friendly url like `/posts/09/03/2020/post-title` = target_link but have it pull content from `index.php?/page=posts&id=1` = actual_link

Answer (score -1):

You will need htaccess rules to do it. I dont know how long you have searched but in 5 seconds i found the following - [How to create friendly URL in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812571/how-to-create-friendly-url-in-php) and this [Date and name based friendly URL using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235903/date-and-name-based-friendly-url-using-htaccess)

Its not a real answer since you dont provide much more light about what data you have in your database since its not just posts in wordpress. Its a bit more complicated than that.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using htaccess to do this since I want to automate this process

Comment: so what htaccess string should be used to achieve this goal? Like /post/09/04/2020/the-blog-title